# How to Run Unit Tests for Multiple Build Schemes in Xcode Project using CircleCI?

Tags: ios, circleci

I have an Xcode project with a single .xcworkspace file containing multiple build schemes. I am using CircleCI for continuous integration, and I want to configure it to run unit tests for all these build schemes whenever a developer commits code to any branch.

I have already set up a config.yaml file for CircleCI, but I'm unsure how to modify it to achieve this. Specifically, I need assistance in dynamically running unit tests for each build scheme present in the Xcode workspace.

Could someone guide how to modify the CircleCI configuration (config.yaml) to achieve this? Additionally, any insights or best practices regarding running unit tests for multiple build schemes in Xcode projects with CircleCI would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!